# Клик по DOM элементу с id для открытия infoWindow с идентичным id, google maps

Tags: javascript, json, google-maps-api

Есть карта с маркерами которые представлены в виде массива, у которых разные infoWindow, в каждом из которых есть кнопка. Есть боковое меню, где представлены элементы со своим id. При клике на элемент нужно открывать маркер с таким-же id. На данный момент открывается только последний маркер из массива. После этого, при клике на кнопку нужно менять иконку у ЭТОГО маркера. На этом все.

Как при клике на DOM элемент с id, открывать infoWindow с идентичным id? Чтобы все работало исправно и при клике на кнопку иконка успешно менялась у ЭТОГО маркера.
Буду очень благодарен за ответ, ибо мучаюсь уже несколько дней.

Answer (score 0):

Создайте ассоциативный список ваших маркеров:

```
var markers = {};
```

Теперь, когда вы создаете маркеры, сохраняйте их в этом списке с текущим id:

```
// здесь id совпадает с id DOM элемента
markers[id] = new google.maps.Marker({...});
```

Далее, при клике на DOM `element`, быстро находите этот маркер и делаете с ним что угодно, меняете, иконку, открываете инфо-окно и т.д.:

```
var myMarker = markers[element.id];
```

Чтобы не было коллизий названий ваших id со свойствами и методами Object, можно сделать так, чтобы ваши id начинались с какого-нибудь префикса, например:

```
// рекомендуемые названия id
'el_mark_01'    
'el_mark_02'    
'el_mark_03'
```

Comment: Благодарю за быстрый ответ, но это решение мне не помогает. Возможно я туплю, тогда прошу описать решение подробнее, если не трудно.
Перефразирую свою задачу:

Есть боковое меню. Есть гугл-карта на которой 131 маркер, каждый со своей информацией. В боковом меню столько же элементов сколько и маркеров на карте.

Пример: Есть элемент с id - A, и маркер с id - A. При клике на элемент с таким id должен открываться маркер с идентичным id. После этого при клике на кнопку в infoWindow нужно менять иконку у этого маркера

Comment: Когда маркеры уже находятся на карте, вы не сможете получить их список обратно, чтобы пробежаться по нему и найти искомый маркер. В API нет функции наподобие map.getMarkers(), для получения списка всех маркеров. Поэтому, вам нужно найти в ВАШЕМ КОДЕ то место, где эти маркеры создаются и запомнить все эти маркеры в JS-массив. Затем закинуть их на карту... Но массив с сылками на маркеры хранить, чтобы быстро находить в нем нужный маркер.

Comment: Я не очень силен в js, а уж тем-более в гугл-картах, можете описать на примере? Все-равно спасибо за ответ